# join audio file in specific time of the video ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i am trying to use the code bellow to merge an audio file at specific time (6th second of my input video) and create a new video autput file but i cant make it work.

```
<?php

exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -sameq -i /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/video/full.mp4 -itsoffet 6 -i /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/sounds/names/george.mp3 /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/upload/sample.mpg");


?>
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do not use `-sameq`.  See this answer: [`sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo in your command: `-itsoffet` should be `-itsoffset`.

Secondly, it seems there's [a bug](http://roundup.libav.org/issue359) affecting `-itsoffset`.

Take a look at these identical/similar questions:

- [Add audio (with an offset) to video with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426179/add-audio-with-an-offset-to-video-with-ffmpeg)
- [delay audio with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643348/delay-audio-with-ffmpeg)
- [Add multiple audio files to video at specific points using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579952/add-multiple-audio-files-to-video-at-specific-points-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: That is the old bug tracker and may not apply to current FFmpeg.